# Canon MF-3010 printer driver not found!

Tags: 12.10, drivers, 64-bit, printing, canon

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 x64 and Canon MF-3010 printer. How will I use it? In printers it couldn't find any driver. In recommended driver it didn't work. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I am not a user of it but would like to share a link that can help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2089269

Comment: i tried and installed driver but not working

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried download the package from http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=imageCLASS+MF3010&menu=download&filter=0&tagname=g_os&g_os=Linux ? The driver included in the zip package in Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian worked for me.

Comment: i tried this and other methods but didnt work.